# jquery autocomplete with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am using a jQuery autocomplete with the codeigniter framework.

This currently works 100%.

my model is:

```
  function get_sku_code($q){
    $this->db->select('ProductCode');
    $this->db->like('ProductCode', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('ProductList');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ProductCode'])); //build an array
      }
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row_set));

    }
  }
```

My View javascript is:

```
 $("#product").autocomplete( 
 { 
 source: "get_sku_codes", 
 messages: 
 { 
 noResults: '', 
 results: function() {} 
 }, 
 select: function( event, ui ) 
 { 
  var selectedObj = ui.item; 
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
 $("#product").parent().parent().find('input[id^="price"]').val(result[0]);
 $("#product").parent().parent().find('input[id^="adjustedprice"]').val(result[0]);
 }); 
 } 
 });
```

As mentioned this works 100%. The one issue I am having is that if there is no database match, the autocomplete list is simply blank. Is there a way to return 'no matches in database' when the model returns no values? should I do this with jquery or with the codeigniter mysql request?

Thanks as always,

**Controller - get_sku_codes**

```
 function get_sku_codes(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->Sales_model->get_sku_code($q);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all according to the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern you should not echo anything in your Model. All this logic must be at the Controller from which the View will get the data.

Change your Model to this:

```
  function get_sku_code($q){
    $this->db->select('ProductCode');
    $this->db->like('ProductCode', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('ProductList');
    $row_set = array();
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ProductCode'])); //build an array
      }
     return $row_set;
  }
```

And your Controller to this:

```
  function get_sku_codes(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $output = $this->Sales_model->get_sku_code($q);
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($output));
    }
  }
```

Then in your View you can create a `<span id="noMatches"></span>` element somewhere below or next to the `<input id="product">` to display your 'No matches' message when the returning result is empty.

```
    $("#product").autocomplete(
 { 
    source: "get_sku_codes", 
    response: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            $("#noMatches").html("No matches");
        } else {
            $("#noMatches").empty();
        }
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) 
    { 
        var selectedObj = ui.item; 
         $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) { 
             $("#product").parent().parent().find('input[id^="price"]').val(result[0]);
             $("#product").parent().parent().find('input[id^="adjustedprice"]').val(result[0]);
         }); 
    } 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Sport Billy, you are correct but when I do populate this nothing appears, simply 'nothing'. any ideas as to why? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sports Billy, thanks for your efforts, appreciated. I tried as you suggested but still blank :-( developer tools XHR shows no HTML response at all so not sure its being passed correctly. Any other advice? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Billy, it is in the question already, in my model. Thanks.

Comment: Then you have a typo. In your model you have `get_sku_code` rather than `get_sku_codes` that you have in your JS. Also you are expecting a variable `$q` in order to fetch results from db, but you are not sending any data when using the `jQuery .autocomplete()` . You said that it is working and is viewing results, if it has, but i cannot figure out how it does it.

Comment: Sorry billy, you are correct. get_sku_code is my model, I have added get_sku_codes (controller) to the question. thanks again.

Comment: Ok changed my whole answer. Check it