# How to get input from Jquery live search in database for bonfire Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My `view` customer folder contains 2 files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery autocomplete with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765692/jquery-autocomplete-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

For best practice your code in showUtility view page should be in controllr customer in showUtility function which you already created. Loading view is not necessary.
Any ways just to work your logic you need to add some more after query and getting result.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->utility_name;
        break;

}
exit ();
```

Comment: customer/showUtility I got error : Undefined index: key